# How to make sense of this Object.inspect result?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and trying to learn the ropes.  I have an object returned from a call to the Twitter API.  I'd like to loop through the :users below and be able to print out their different attributes... like :id, :screenname, etc.

BTW, these are all followers on twitter.  So the object is called "Followers" and this is what I'm calling to get the inspect... "followers.inspect"

The gist of the followers.inspect is here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7966898/raw/938a0048d08f44415229b98a1adef96c4946ce8d/gistfile1.txt

My problem is that I'm having a hard time figuring out how this .inspect print out matches up to what I should be looking for.

So the code I've written to try to work through this is...

```
followers.users.each do |i|
   puts "#{i.name} has user id #{i.id_str}"
end
```

The error I'm getting is that there is no method called users.

Sorry, I'm sure this is a very simple question but have just gotten stuck!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can quickly see, the object you have contains a hash `@attrs` with a key `:users`.
So, it should be something like:

```
followers.attrs[:users].each do |i|
    puts "#{i.name} has user id #{i.id_str}"
end
```

Maybe you'll also need to use `i[:name]` since all those users are also hashes, not objects with methods, but my Ruby is a bit rusty, so I don't know if those methods are automatically available when a key is present in a hash.

Anyway: `{:key => "value"}` in inspect means that it's a hash with keys and values, that you access like: `nameofhash[:key]`

`[{:key => "value"},{:key => "value"}]` means it's a array with two seperate hashes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but that doesn't seem to be working.  I've slimmed down the code a bit to its bare bones and here is what I put in...

    followers.attrs[:users].each do |i|
      "#{i.inspect}"
    end

Note: I'm using this in sinatra so I don't need to use puts... just the "".  The error I'm getting now is "NoMethodError at /followers/toast
undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:0x007f89e28fb7e0>"